# UITabBarContoller "More" option top bar color

Tags: iphone

I have a TabBarController with top black navigation bar, but once i navigate to "More" option, the top bar is becoming default blue. I have separate nav.controllers in the tab bar which all are set to top black nav. bar. But how the more option is only getting in blue ? Is there any way to change it's color ? Please help

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution. Do share if any one have other thoughts.

My solution :

if (self.moreNavigationController) {
      self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }